# How does one add constraints with Vapor?

Tags: vapor-fluent

How does one define constraints via Vapor?  Here's my latest attempt:

```swift
database.schema(Thingmabob.schema)
    .id()
    .field("parentID", .uuid, .required, .references(Stuff.schema, .id))
    .field("name", .string, .required)
    .field("isDocumened", .bool, .required)
    .field("value1", .uint, .required)
    .field("value2", .uint)
    .constraint(.custom("value2 > value1 + 1"))        // << "syntax error"
    .create()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is two folds:

**1)** Seems the documentation — HA! — forgot to mention that any field mentionned in the `.constraint(.custom( ... ))` is set to lowercase.  So if you have a field/column like `.constraint(.custom("isDocumented ...")`, the value in the constraint becomes `isdocumented` which fails to matches any column.  Just *beautiful!*

**2)** Also, note that, while I'm using the `.constraint()` API, the framework has no idea what do to with it... I thus have to write the full statement `CHECK notcamelcase > alsonotcamelcase` (not just `notcamelcase > alsonotcamelcase`).   Not sure why `.constraint()` isn't named `.arbitrarySQLSegment()` as that would've been more accurate and helpful than all that documentation I've read.